# How To Prevent Adding New Properties To Cosmos DB Document With The Partial Document Update Feature

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using this Nuget Package in my ASP.NET project for CRUD operations with Azure Cosmos DB: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3

I'm working on update API, and have just found that the SDK provides partial update functionality via the PatchOperation class, which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update).

However, I realized that user can add new property with Add operations, such as

```
{"op": "add", "path": "/color", "value": "red"}
```

That would give the end users capability to add unwanted properties, which could lead to many issues. Is there a way to limit the use of Add operation? However, I do want to allow end users to add values to an existing array, so that I cannot simply disable all Add operations by checking against the word "add". I have the document mapped to an Entity model class, can I make use of strong-type check to simplify it? I can think of an awkward approach, which is to parse the JSON path (like "/foo/bar/baz/0/qux") and use .NET reflection to look up the property on the entity class. But I don't want to go down that road, as I expect the SDK should have a native solution.

What options do I have? Thanks.

Comment: _"That would give the end users capability to add unwanted properties, which could lead to many issues."_ Why would you give _the end user_ such a direct access? I'd consider that a security risk to begin with.

Comment: If you have an Entity Class, how would _the end user_ add _a property_?

Comment: How you validate/filter user-provided data is really up to you (maybe in your own API that your UI interacts with?). This really has nothing to do with a particular Cosmos DB API/SDK call, however, since only your app is using the various API/SDK calls, somewhere (hopefully) in your app layer where (hopefully) a user would never have access to.

Comment: Using the Entity model class's strong typing is one strategy you might employ. To make sure that the Add operation is only permitted on those particular properties, you can specify a whitelist of properties that are permitted to be modified and use that to verify against any incoming PatchOperation objects.